# Now that Articles 17 & 11 have passed, what should indie developers do?

Tags: legal, copyright

Since on the 26th of March 2019 the EU has voted in favor of Articles 17 (previously known as Article 13) and 11, what should an indie developer who is based in the EU do to setup a game and a website for the game s/he develops?

I'm taking into consideration the following:

- The developer has a website for the game he publishes.
- The developer also has an account system on the said website (required by the game for customizability and authentication).
- The developer sells the game on his/her own website (for 100% profit).
- The indie developer is funding the game entirely from his/her own money (no investors).
- The game is fully customizable, i.e. all text, textures, sounds and models can be changed.
- The marketing is handled only by the game developer. This also takes into consideration the platforms which are available in the EU when these Articles take effect.

I'm curious about this as I'm based in the EU and wish to create a game with a lot of user customizability (to the level that the game's assets are all replaced by custom ones), but I'm unsure of how Articles 17 (upload filter) and 11 (link tax) will affect me. I'm also concerned about how link tax will affect the website, and how marketing is supposed to be done on the EU internet.

Comment: @TomTsagk it sounds like Hyblocker is asking about user-generated content. Hyblocker, can you please clarify whether your game allows players to upload this customized content to your server to display/share with other players? We can't give advice universal to all indie developers, but we can try to solve your specific problem if you describe in more detail how your game functions.

Comment: @TomTsagk I've clarified more in the question.

Comment: @TomTsagk I'm also concerned about marketing, as it will now be harder to market on the internet if you're in the EU.

Comment: @Hyblocker You can still market it as-is without any issues. You can mention things like "you can create your own content" etc etc, as long as you don't include protected content anywhere it's being marketed. I believe Articles 13 and 11 only touch areas when a user is generating and uploading content, that you should filter it, before it's available to other users. I'm not a lawyer, so take everything I say with a grain of salt.

Comment: What specifically about operating & marketing your game gets harder in this case? Please err on the side of being maximally explicit and specific about the problems you have in mind, bearing in mind that we know nothing about your game's features or marketing plan, and nobody knows anything much yet about how Articles 11/13 might be implemented by member states. We need concrete details to be able to offer you useful advice — for instance, as I asked you earlier, does your server host & distribute players' custom assets?

Comment: @DmGregory I was thinking of making users host servers and the owner of the server chooses whether to use the default assets or custom ones s/he provided. The marketing concerns I have are more about what platforms are going to be available to the European market, as platforms like YouTube will probably cease to operate entirely in the EU.

Comment: That's a start. Now **edit your question** to ensure all of that detail is up front, not hidden away in the comment thread.

Comment: By the way: A few days before the voting the whole directive got reordered. The controversial article about upload filters is now article 17. Article 13 is about mediation now.

Comment: @Philipp Ah, didn't know that, I'll edit the title.

Comment: Uh.. move to chat perhaps?

Comment: @TimHolt Unfortunately, The OP does not have enough rep to use the chat.

Comment: @Hyblocker, as someone who's not part of the EU it is not clear exactly what regulations these are, nor what it is they ask for that you feel perhaps game developers should possibly deliver to customers.  Can you clarify what these measures are, and what it is they ask for that prompts you to ask your specific question?    Personally  I'm not clear which 11 and 17 you refer to.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Copyright_in_the_Digital_Single_Market states for example, "articles 11 and 13 (renumbered 15 and 17[...]).."  Are you talking about 15 and 17?  Or a new 11?

Comment: Your Question made me look up these articles.  This could be devestating for EU developers, twitch and youtube are some of the best ways to advertise, and now their going to be throttled.

Answer (score 1):

Link Tax means something like this:
For a company to use your content on their website, you must license them, and they must pay an appropriate fee before they can publish some part of your content.
And Upload Filter means something like this:

 The Upload Filters are algorithms to prevent copywritten content from being published without the necessary developer permission.

 So long as you own everything in the game, you could definitely go through with it without worry. Upload Filter and Link Tax wouldn't affect you publishing your own content because **you own it.** If changing assets is done on the user-end, that's the user problem in terms of legality, not yours. This seems to comply with the EU laws.